# Joomla 3 - Menu Search engine friendly URL

Tags: php, joomla, menu, module

I am coding an own Joomla menu-module. Now I am asking how to build the correct URL of the menu items. So far:

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$menu = $app->getMenu();    
$active = $menu->getActive();
$items = $menu->getItems('menutype', 'mainmenu');

foreach($items as $i => $item) {

 echo '<li><a href="'.$item->link.'">'.$item->title.'</a></li>';

}
```

I know that I can get the ->link or the ->alias, but how do I know what the user customized in Joomla? So if he wants to use SearchEngineFriendly URL so I have to use ->alias for URL, but how do I know? What is the best way to create a proper URL-Link for the menu?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

Use JRoute, like that:

```
echo '<li><a href="'.JRoute::_($item->link).'">'.$item->title.'</a></li>'
```

Comment: it has no effect to me though, it always shows the id, no matter what is selected in Joomla. Maybe this is a bit more complicated than just using JRoute. After using mod_menu this works, thanks for your help